# Automatically create spreadsheet, triggered by new selection from Dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to automate teaching feedback distribution for doctors on a Critical Care Unit. Currently we are inputting the feedback on to a Google Form and it it is then populated into a spreadsheet, to then be distributed.

I have used the below function to create individual sheets for each persons feedback, which will then keep updating throughout the year as they do more sessions, meaning that I only need to share the initial link with each person once.

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_url", "Form responses 1!A1:G159"), "select*WHERE Col3='presenter_name'")

The step I am struggling to automate is the creation of a new spreadsheet, when a new option from the dropdown is used (ie a new teacher presents). Ideally this would also include their name in the title.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean an option from a dropdown in Google Form?

Comment: Both the response sheet and the Google form have dropdowns, so could be triggered by a new response in either, although I suspect the sheet would be easier

Comment: An do you want the script to trigger onFormSubmit, or after manual edit in the spreadsheet? (Or both?)

Comment: Either I think would work as the spreadsheet is dependent upon the Form inputs, but only when it's a new presenter, if there's already a sheet currently it's set to just accumulate feedback over the year

Answer (score 1):

If every presenter has his/her own spreadsheet, and
if every spreadsheet has a name which can be related to a presenter, and
if the spreadsheets are kept in a specific folder,
an array of spreadsheet names can be made (with DriveApp).

If the name of a presenter can not be related to a spreadsheet name in the array,
a new spreadsheet has to be made.

Something like this?

```
function BlaBlaBla(){

var presenterName = "ABCDE"; //get this with appscript out of the spreadsheet

var specificFolderId = "XXXX"; //id of the specific folder
var ssFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById(specificFolderId).getFiles();
var ssFileNames = [];

  while (ssFiles.hasNext()) {
    var ssFile = ssFiles.next();
    var ssFileName = ssFile.getName();
    ssFileNames.push(ssFileName);
  }

  var presenterNamePlus = "RMH CCU Teaching Feedback " + presenterName;
  if(ssFileNames.indexOf(presenterNamePLus) == -1){

    SpreadsheetApp.create(presenterNamePlus);

    //move new spreadsheet to specific folder

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.

So each presenter has their own spreadsheet, all kept in a specific folder yes (separate from the master sheet).

In terms of names, they would be along the lines of "RMH CCU Teaching Feedback presenter_name"

Answer (score 0):

### In Apps Script you can run scripts on [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

In your case,  `onEdit` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) and the [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onFormSubmit` would be the more suitable

> OnFormSubmit trigger bound to destination spreadsheet

- You retrieve the item response corresponding to the dropdown question of interest and evaluate its value
- In an `if` statement you specify that a new spreadsheet should be created if the value is equal to value of interest

> OnEdit trigger

- You can specify a column to watch and a value to watch for
- An `if` statement will be fulfilled if a cell in the specified column has been changed to the dropdown option of interest (e.g. "a new teacher presents");
- In both cases, the triggers can call a functio that will retrieve data from other cells of the row with the edited dropdown (e.g. name) (or the last row in case of the onFormSubmit trigger) and create a spreadsheet with the name as specified in the cell of interest

Sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
//modify the column number if necessary
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 3 && e.value == "a new teacher presents"){
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    createNewSpreadsheet(row);
  }
}


function BindOnSubmitToMe(e){
// modify the question number if necessary
  if (e.values[2] == "a new teacher presents"){
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    createNewSpreadsheet(row);
  }
}


function createNewSpreadsheet(row){
  Logger.log("create");
  var nameColumn = 1;
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(row, nameColumn).getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
}
```